# Minor ticks for pcolor with log-log scaling

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The following code does almost exactly what I want (MATLAB R2010a)

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(logspace(-1,1,5),logspace(0,7,5));

pcolor(x,y,x.*y); shading interp;
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log', 'YScale', 'log');
set(gca,'YMinorTick','on');
set(gca,'Layer','top');
```

It makes a plot in which the grid lines are not showing, but both major and minor tick marks are visible.  However, when I replace the first line by

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(logspace(-1,1,10),logspace(0,7,10));
```

(that is, when I increase the resolution) suddenly the minor tick marks dissappear.  How, then, can log-scaled minor tick marks be used on a pcolor plot of a large data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab does not offer much control over the minor grids and ticks. You can set their visibility on or off (obviously with limitation you already suffered), but you cannot set their value/position/number etc ...

The way around it is to completely turn off all ticks and grid on the axis which holds your `pcolor` plot, then create a transparent empty `axes` on top of it, with the grid properties that you define.

Because there is no plot or other graphic object in this empty `axes`, Matlab will behave much better regarding the properties that you set (it won't try to be smart and change some stuff in the background).

So for your case, it would be something along these lines:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(logspace(-1,1,10),logspace(0,7,10));
pcolor(x,y,x.*y); shading interp;
colormap(flipud(gray(64))) %// just so the grid lines are more visible

axbot = gca ;              %// retrieve the handle of the current axis
set(axbot, 'XScale', 'log', 'YScale', 'log');
axis off                   %// remove all ticks/grid etc...

%// now create the "overlay" axes, which replicate some of the properties of the underlying axis (position/limits etc ...)
axtop = axes('Position',get(axbot,'Position'),'Color','none',...
            'Xlim',get(axbot,'XLim'), 'Ylim',get(axbot,'YLim'),...
            'XScale', 'log', 'YScale', 'log' , ...
            'YMinorTick','on' , 'YMinorGrid','off') ;
```

Note that some properties are simply copied from the underlying `axes`, and some other are set explicitly (like `YMinorTick` and `YMinorGrid`).

This will plot:
[image: logticks]

If you want the Y minor grid to show as well, just change `YMinorGrid` to `on`.

---

If you also want the Y ticks marks on the right, you just have to repeat the same thing (almost). Add another axes, this time specifying the `XAxisLocation` to `Top` and `YAxisLocation` to `right`.

```
axtopright = axes('Position',get(axbot,'Position'),'Color','none',...
            'Xlim',get(axbot,'XLim'), 'Ylim',get(axbot,'YLim'),...
            'XScale', 'log', 'YScale', 'log' , ...
            'YMinorTick','on' , 'YMinorGrid','off' , ...
            'XAxisLocation', 'Top','YAxisLocation','right' ) ;
```

Comment: This is great, Hoki.  Just one question: is it possible to make ticks on all four sides of the graph?